# Magento 2: 'Tax Class' is not showing in products from admin panel

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

After migrating data from Magento 1 to Magento 2, i can not see 'Tax Class' attribute from admin panel while editing a product. 'Stock Status' attribute is also missing. But when i create new product, then these attributes can be seen. The problem with migrated products only.

Any solution?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this maybe?

Comment: Yes, expand all the tabs of product. You will definitely find it somewhere.

Comment: Yep, It was hidden in one of the Migration_* attribute groups. I found it yesterday, but thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue so you need to change the ***catalog_eav_attribute*** table so connect step connect **PHPMyAdmin** and follow the below step given :

**Step 1:** Select the database are you using and run the below command

> SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` LIKE
> '%tax_class_id%'

[image]

**Step 2:** run the below query

> SELECT * FROM `catalog_eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_id` = 136

[image]

Step 3 : change the value of ***apply_to*** filed like "**simple,virtual,downloadable,configurable,bundle**"

[image]

I am ***100%*** sure your issue resolve after apply the above solution.

***Happy coding....***

Comment: Working fine, Thank you!

Comment: @umair ayub  please accept my question if working fine thanks.