# Magento 2 - Field "Tax Class" not showing

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, tax, attribute-set

I have the problem that for a custom new product type there are no taxes getting calculated and are always 0.

I found a solution [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8bQGm.png). It says there is a dropdown in the product details called **Tax Class**:

[image]

But there is no such field for me (on any product type). The **attribute set** is set to `default`.

[image]

Attribute Set "Default":

[image]

As you can see an attribute with name "tax_class_id" already exist in this attribute set, but why is it not showing?

Comment: Hi Black, usually the 'tax_class_id' is inside the advanced_pricing options. I don't know if your custom product has that. But just in case...

Comment: It does not have it. Thx for the info.

Answer (score 1):

If you just create a new Product Type, admin product form does not contain some standard fields like Price and Tax Class. You need to associate this standard common attributes with your new Product Type via InstallData/UpgradeData scripts. Example:

```
$productEntityTypeId = $eavSetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY);
$fieldsCommon = [ // list of fields you need
    'tax_class_id'
];
foreach ($fieldsCommon as $field) {
    $applyTo = explode(
        ',',
        $eavSetup->getAttribute($productEntityTypeId, $field, 'apply_to')
    );
    if (!in_array('<new-type-code>', $applyTo)) {
        $applyTo[] = '<new-type-code>';
        $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
            $productEntityTypeId,
            $field,
            'apply_to',
            implode(',', $applyTo)
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue so you need to change the ***catalog_eav_attribute*** table so connect step connect **PHPMyAdmin** and follow the below step given :

**Step 1:** Select the database are you using and run the below command

> SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` LIKE
> '%tax_class_id%'

[image]

**Step 2:** run the below query

> SELECT * FROM `catalog_eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_id` = 136

[image]

Step 3 : change the value of ***apply_to*** filed like "**simple,virtual,downloadable,configurable,bundle**"

[image]

I am ***100%*** sure your issue resolve after apply the above solution.

***Happy coding....***

reference link -> [Magento 2: 'Tax Class' is not showing in products from admin panel](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208508/magento-2-tax-class-is-not-showing-in-products-from-admin-panel/334969#334969)

Answer (score 0):

After Vishals suggested solution (which worked for me, thank you): Do not forget to run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` command.